# SQL Server - Unpivot (double) or Cross Apply for Double Unpivot?

Tags: sql-server, unpivot, cross-apply

I'm trying to figure out how to do a double Unpivot efficiently.

I know Unpivot; it takes the selected columns (Wizards, Apples, Bananas, Books) and jams them into two columns, generally the categorical descriptor and the value itself -- and these 2 new columns need names (Stuff_type, Stuff_count).

Sometimes though you have a collection of columns and want to unpivot both. Such as

```
    apple_count, apple_weight, wizard_count, wizard_weight, book_count, book_weight
        1,           12.0,         2,           23.0,           3,        34.0
```

Is there an effective way to unpivot both these columns? So in essence you would return the following:

```
Item_Name, Item_Weight, Item_Count
apple         12.0          1
wizard        23.0          2
```

Does this require two unpivots, or is there is a more efficient way?

Would cross apply be more elegant here?

Comment: Hmm I suppose cross-apply seems to work just fine. It does carry with it 'null' values unlike unpivot (unpivot seems to filter out null rows by default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option that will "dynamically" unpivot your data without actually using Dynamic SQL.  I use an helper TVF here, but that can easily be converted into a CROSS APPLY

**Example**

```
Select Item_Name   = left(Item,charindex('_',Item+'_')-1)
      ,Item_Weight = max(case  when Item like '%_weight' then convert(decimal(10,1),Value) end)
      ,Item_Count  = max(case  when Item like '%_count'  then convert(int,Value) end)
 From   YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-XML-UnPivot-Row]((Select A.* for XML Raw)) b
 Group By left(Item,charindex('_',Item+'_')-1)
```

**Returns**

```
Item_Name   Item_Weight Item_Count
apple       12.0        1
book        34.0        3
wizard      23.0        2
```

**The Function if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-XML-UnPivot-Row](@XML xml)
Returns Table 
As
Return ( 
        Select Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
              ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')
         From  @XML.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
)

/*
Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-XML-UnPivot-Row]((Select A.* for XML RAW)) B
*/
```

Comment: nice. I'll have to test this out. I'm not as familiar with 'xml/ nodes' as it related to SQL Server but looks fairly useful

Comment: @user45867  Happy to help.  Truth be told, I too was a late adopter of XML  :)